# angular ui-router logout state doesn't redirect to login until refresh the page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What I need that on click on logout link ,

we call logout method of the *AuthService* to clear cookie data and than user should redirected on login page.

But it seem's not working. page being stay on */logout* page and user need to refresh the page than it goes to /login page. why so?

here is my relevant code

```
.state("logout", {
          url: '/logout',
          data: {
              requiresAuth: true
          },
          controller:['$state', 'AuthService', function($state, AuthService) {
                      AuthService.logout();
                      $state.transitionTo('login', null, { reload :true});
           }]
      })
```

and here is relevant AuthService method

```
app.factory('AuthService', function($log, $http, $q, $cookies){
 authService.logout = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
          method: "GET",
          url: '/app/logout.json'
        }).then(function(result) {
          $cookies.remove('currentUser');
          deferred.resolve(result);
        }, function(error) {
          deferred.reject(error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

Note : when I write /logout in URL and hit it than it goes to login page.

Comment: I have tried with `$state.go()` instead of `$state.transitionTo()`  but no success :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `factory` code complete as posted? If yes, I am afraid you have syntax error. This is because `authService` will be `undefined`.

You will have to first declare the `authService` as an object, and then return that object in your factory function. Else, your `AuthService` service will go haywire when injected.

```
app.factory('AuthService', ['$log', '$http', '$q', '$cookies', function($log, $http, $q, $cookies) {
  //declare your authService variable first, as an object.
  var authService = {};
  //now you are declaring a method inside this object,named logout
  authService.logout = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: 'logout.json'
    }).then(function(result) {
      $cookies.remove('currentUser');
      deferred.resolve(result);
    }, function(error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };
  //remember to return this object so that it can be used as a service
  return authService;
}])
```

I have pretty much mocked an example as closely and as relevant as your code. It works fine. Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mctW24GePUW0JuwLCDZg?p=preview).

One gentle reminder though: at the controller of your `logout` state, you would want to only do `$state.transitionTo` **AFTER** AuthService has been resolved. Something like this:

```
AuthService.logout().then(function() {
  $state.transitionTo('login', null, {
    reload: true
  });
},function(){
  //handle error here
})
```

I did not change that in the plnkr, since this is your app and you should be clear with what you are achieving.

Comment: Yes, I have defined the authservice and other methods; just posted the relevant code. and thanks. you `.then` solution works like charm